# inserting of data with 80+ columns and thousands of rows with python and rabbitmq

Tags: python, sql-server, rabbitmq

It's been bugging me for days on how to insert large amount of data (as specified in the title). And I am stuck.

I am using python 2.7, sql server 2005 with pyodbc,  and rabbitmq on this.

The scenario is I will send a query from one table then when received, it will be inserted to another table. I have tried using bulk but it's not working because it can't find the directory specified, I even used the os.path and it returned False, allow everyone to all the folders that I am using. So, Insert into is my other option and i am thinking of looping through the values/columns  to declare 80+ variables. I was thinking I will get the column count and store it in a list. Is this idea possible? Or is there anyway I can do it?

I have tried googling it and searching it here in SO, but there isn't one that I can find.

---

```
    #splits the message receive(body)
splitter = body.split(',')
for row in cursor.columns(table='tbltemp'):
    a = row.ordinal_position
    b = row.column_name
print "Content:" , a, b, splitter[a-1]
cursor.execute ('insert into tbltemp ? values(?)', (a, splitter[a]))
print "done"
```

---

In this code, I can now get the column, ordinal number, and the corresponding data input. all is left is with the insert statement

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused about your question. On the one hand you talk about "tables" (sending a query to one table and write it to another), but afterwards, you talk about directories.

My best guess of the flow of events is the following:

Given an existing database and a table with data inside you probably have to do something like the following:

1. Connect to the database
2. Prepare the query
3. Send the query to the database engine
4. Retrieve a cursor to the query result
5. Find out metadata on the returned result (number of columns and rows)
6. Prepare the output table
7. Iterate over the cursor and write the result to the output table
8. Commit the results
9. Close the connection to the database

Where in this process do you get stuck? Do you have code samples that work/don't work?

Just for your information. I have a similar setup with Python, RabbitMQ  and a database. However, instead of a SQL database, I use MongoDb and pass around JSON files and Python lists/dictionaries.

Comment: I am stuck starting at number 5 and your guess is correct. That is the flow of the process. I was instructed to use SQL database on this one.

Comment: in number 4, I used a split format in order to retrieve the results and be able to insert it to the database. is that correct?

Comment: I have not worked with pyodbc for a long time, but I quickly looked at the documentation for the cursor https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor. In particular note the "rowcount" variable and the cursor.tables() and cursor.columns() methods. These should provide the functionality that you need. If you want more specific help, it would be helpful if you provide self contained parts of the code you have trouble with.

Comment: I added the piece in my code. It's all I have up until now because I am still looking for ways how to do it. Your link helped me a lot. I overlooked that cursor.columns() part and was using the `select column_name...` until I saw what was in the docs. I hope you'll be patient with me. Thank you.